# JTextPane lightweight alternatives?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextcomponent

I am working on simple Unix `tail` like utility (my first work in Java). There are a lots already available but none suit my specific requirements. I need additional log analysis help feature, config sharing, bookmark, edit, regex support and a bit more. The closest commercial product that I can relate to is [bareTail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/).

I am almost through with implementation, but stuck on limitations with TextArea in Java. I cannot set different background color for lines in TextArea. Though I can do this in JTextPane, but it looks to be quiet heavy is there anything that's in between the two.

Answer (score 1):

[JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) might be the one which you are looking for. It supports custom highlighting and JTextPane extends JEditorPane

Comment: Anything better ? I need not save it in HTML / RTF formatting. Just highlight with different back ground color in runtime.

Comment: You want to set different background color for entire text component or only selected lines?

Comment: only selected lines..., say in a file with 100 lines, 10 lines are in blue and some 15 in red and so on, rest with out background color.